# Is there a way for WebAssembly applications be run as stand alone or self hosted?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, opensilver

We're currently looking at OpenSilver, which is a open-source reimplementation of Silverlight.
It runs on browsers via WebAssembly. It uses Mono for WebAssembly and Microsoft Blazor.
It runs without the need for browser extensions.

The examples I've seen so far require it be hosted in IIS. 
From within Visual studio, it can be hosted via IIS Express or a simulator.

Our clients have security requirements that prohibit them from web applications (hosted in IIS).

We are evaluating OpenSilver as a potential cross platform solution.

Is there any way to run as a standard alone or self hosted application?
I know Qt/QML has a browser control that let's you load html pages directly.
I'm pretty sure that's not going to help us at all.
Are there any alternatives for this?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can "run" it with any hosting.
All you need is to build(publish) your solution and host it as a static website.